# how to check sphinx version?

Tags: sphinx

I install a sphinx search engine a couple months ago, as time pass, I don't remember that sphinx version I installed.

how to check my system sphinx version?

Answer (score 44):

May be just run the command `searchd` without any parameter

It shows following when I just tried

```
Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117)
Copyright (c) 2001-20009, Andrew Aksyonoff

....
```

Answer (score 38):

just type in terminal:

```
sphinx-build --version
```

Answer (score 37):

Run searchd with '--help' parameter which show the searchd version:

```
searchd --help
Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117)
Copyright (c) 2001-2009, Andrew Aksyonoff
```

Comment: search initially worked for me, but after upgrading an x86-64 package I needed to do `searchd --help`

Answer (score 8):

Here are few ways to do it from python itself:

```
$ python -c 'import sphinx; print sphinx.__version__'
'1.1.3'
```

The same of above, with a single instruction variant:

```
$ python -c 'print __import__("sphinx").__version__'
'1.1.3'
```

Or, using `pkg_resources`:

```
$ python -c 'import pkg_resources; print pkg_resources.require("sphinx")[0].version'
'1.1.3'
```

The same of above, with a single instruction variant:

```
$ python -c 'print __import__("pkg_resources").require("sphinx")[0].version'
'1.1.3'
```

Comment: Wrong sphinx! The question was about the sql search tool sphinx. This did answer my question though. I was looking for the python one, so thanks! :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can also just connect with the MySQL client.

```
% mysql --host=sphinx.example.com --port=9306 --protocol=tcp
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 2.2.7-id64-release (r4883)
```

There you have the server version.  The `--protocol=tcp` may be needed if the host is localhost.

Comment: This is the version of the MySQL database client that Sphinx is using thus the "--port=9306". The question is "how to check sphinx version?" which can be found from the command line with "searchd" on the Sphinx server. The "searchd" response will include something like "Sphinx 2.2.9-id64-release (rel22-r5006)". This assumes you're running a x86-64 version.

Comment: The version is in the string `Server version: 2.2.7-id64-release (r4883)`.  That is the server version of Sphinx.

Answer (score 4):

> .../sphinx/bin/search

just do it

Comment: You might want to add a "which search" to your "just do it" instructions as I don't think a typical Sphinx install supports such a command. Perhaps you're looking for "searchd"?

Answer (score 0):

First go to the directory which have sphinx

run any one of the command

- search
- searchd
- indexer

or

- indexer --config /home/myuser/sphinx.conf --all
- indexer --rotate --all

Comment: Certainly "searchd" or "indexr" but "search" must be an alias you've setup as that's not a part of a typical Sphinx install. All of the "or" items have nothing to do with the orginal question "how to check sphinx version?"

Answer (score 0):

Typically within the container running Sphinx:

**searchd --status**

```
root@453ba3cefef3:/# searchd --status
Sphinx 2.2.9-id64-release (rel22-r5006)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
```

This assumes you're running a x86-64 version.

Answer (score 0):

Just run command bellow:

```
searchd --version

Sphinx 3.2.1 (commit f152e0b8)
Copyright (c) 2001-2020, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

Built on: Linux alpine38 4.14.69-0-vanilla #1-Alpine SMP Mon Sep 10 19:33:23 UTC 2018 x86_64 Linux
Built with: gcc 6.4.0
Build date: Jan 31 2020
Build type: release
Configure flags:  '--enable-dl' '--with-mysql' '--with-pgsql' '--with-unixodbc' 'CXXFLAGS=-DSPHINX_TAG= -DNDEBUG -O3 -g1 -D__MUSL__' 'LDFLAGS=-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc'
Compiled DB drivers: mysql-dynamic pgsql-dynamic odbc-dynamic
```

**Works only if version 3 and higher**